# Python use Function of a Function inside another File

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, import

I have another beginner question where I cant find a solution by my own, especially because I may name things wrong.

I have two python files. And I need to do this:

File one:

```
def Main():
     def whatever(a,b):
          #do whatever
```

Second file:

```
Import Main
Main.whatever(str a, str b)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You don't. `whatever` is an implementation detail of the function `main`, if it were publicly accessible in the module it would not have been nested.

Comment: An inner function cannot be accessed outside its scope unless you return it from `Main`.

Comment: Thank you for your answere. Than how do I do that. Main is a window with a lable inside. From file two I want to set the Text of a label in Main. How do I have to rebuild my code to access that label's code?

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't import functions like that, you import modules.

If you have a file named `main.py` containing the function `Main`, the you can either:

```
import main
main.Main()
```

or

```
from main import Main
Main()
```

Second, function `whatever` is local in `Main` and doesn't exist after exiting the `Main` function. You might want to use a class for that:

```
class Main(object):
    def whatever(self, a, b):
        # Do something
```

And then call it like this:

```
main = Main()
main.whatever(something, something_else)
```

Comment: You're trying to hammer nails with a kitchen sink :|

Answer (score 0):

You can return function pointer from the Main and use it at other places.

First file:

```
def Main():
 def whatever(a,b):
      #do whatever
 return whatever # Return function pointer
```

Second file:

```
from main import Main
whatever = Main()
whatever(a,b) # Call whatever
```

Answer (score -1):

test.py

```
class Example:
    def printhello():
        print "hello"
```

Other python file can use this

```
import test
ex = test.Example()
```

later  you can use `ex.printhello()`

or

```
from test import printhello
```

you can use only `printhello()`